# How to I detect when a sink moves to the next source?

Tags: rust, rodio

I am using rust with the rodio crate to make a basic command line mp3 player. Everything works fine, except I have no way to display the currently playing song.

I made a Song struct with a title, artist, path, and source. I then made a vector `queue` of `Song` structs to keep track of the song that I am playing and songs that will play next. I appended the sources of the songs to a sink, and made a variable `queueindex` that keeps track of the index of the currently playing song in the queue. The problem? I have no way to tell when a song finishes playing, and thus cannot increment the `queueindex` variable. `sink.empty()` doesn't help because it only returns true when the sink is completely empty. Is there any way to tell when a source finishes playing and another one starts?
Edit: Should I add the full source code to the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Yes, providing more of your source would be helpful.)

I don't have `rodio` set up locally, but the [docs](https://docs.rs/rodio/latest/rodio/source/trait.Source.html#the-source-trait) say that the actual samples of a `Source` are obtained by simply iterating over it, i.e. a `Source` must also be an `Iterator<Item = Sample>`. So, to execute some code when the iterator finishes (to increment the queue index), we will create a `struct SourceWithFn`.

```rust
struct SourceWithFn<S, F>(S, Option<F>);
```

The `struct` must be an `Iterator`, to pass data through from the original source, and to detect when the source finishes.

```rust
impl<S, F> Iterator for SourceWithFn<S, F>
where
    S: Source,
    S::Item: Sample,
    F: FnOnce(),
{
    type Item = S::Item;
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<S::Item> {
        match self.0.next() {
            Some(n) => Some(n),
            None => {
                self.1.take().unwrap()();
                None
            }
        }
    }
    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.0.size_hint()
    }
}
```

Note that the `unwrap` will panic if the iterator is invoked after it has finished. You can change the implementation to `FnMut` (and remove the `Option`) if this is needed.

The `struct` must also be a `Source`:

```rust
impl<S, F> Source for SourceWithFn<S, F>
where
    S: Source,
    S::Item: Sample,
    F: FnOnce(),
{
    #[inline]
    fn current_frame_len(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        self.0.current_frame_len()
    }
    #[inline]
    fn channels(&self) -> u16 {
        self.0.channels()
    }
    #[inline]
    fn sample_rate(&self) -> u32 {
        self.0.sample_rate()
    }
    #[inline]
    fn total_duration(&self) -> Option<Duration> {
        self.0.total_duration()
    }
}
```

And finally, a convenience constructor:

```rust
impl<S, F> SourceWithFn<S, F>
where
    S: Source,
    S::Item: Sample,
    F: FnOnce(),
{
    fn wrap(source: S, f: F) -> Self {
        Self(source, Some(f))
    }
}
```

Now, you can wrap an existing source like so:

```rust
let source = todo!();
let wrapped_source = SourceWithFn::Wrap(source, || queue_index += 1);
```

However, note that `queue_index` is captured mutably by the above! To make this work with multiple sources and `rodio` in general, you might want to put the `queue_index` in a `Cell` or similar.